# Win 8 - customize each window opened from the home page(GridApp Template)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, blend

I've made an application with the Split App Template(similar to GridApp) in Visual C# for Win 8 Tablet.
I have customized the entire home page having only 3 cells and it's fantastic!
now i want to associate to each of this window a customized page...for example from the home page i click on the first cell and it will open a form with various fields(name,phone etc...). if i click on the second cell of the home page it will open a window with a video, if i click on the third it will open a list view...

i've read a lot of tutorial but no one talk about that...

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435892/custom-detail-pages-in-windows-8-grid-application

Answer (score 0):

You should put a button in each one and handle the Tap-events of each one of them and send it to the appropriate page:

```
<Button Tap="Button1_Tap" />
<Button Tap="Button2_Tap" />
<Button Tap="Button3_Tap" />
```

and in your code:

```
public void Button1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(PageAudio));
}

.
.
.
```

NOTE: I entered this code in the editor here, you might have to correct some things for syntax errors.

Comment: this means adding an invisible button on the cell. Thank you for the tips!Is there something better?i don't think it's a best practice!